# DialogFragment will not respect wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

I've got a custom DialogFragment class that looks like this:

```
/**
 * Dialog Fragment containing rating form.
 */
public class RatingDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TAG = "RatingDialog";

    // ...


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_rating, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

        return v;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The root view is a `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">
```

Every single child view has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Yet it looks like this. What could I be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: every component has a minimum height. it looks correct to me. could you clarify your question please?

Comment: I would like the DialogFragment to wrap its content, so it would end at the "Submit" button.

Comment: @hatboysam Better you post you whole xml of dialogFragment to get problem. One of my code have DialogFragment which works('respect')  properly for `wrap_content`.

Comment: @SamStern did you manage to find a proper solution for this?

Answer (score 12):

This was partially an issue in my layout.  At the bottom of my dialog I had a button bar:

```
<!-- Cancel and apply buttons -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/greySecondary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.FilterButton" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/apply"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.FilterButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The first `View` (a spacer) was expanding to fill the viewport, changing it to this fixed it:

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

I also had to add this to `onResume` in the `DialogFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a problem with layouts and dialog fragments. Set it manually instead:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    window.setLayout(your_value, your_value);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

If you need to wrap the content in the fragment, you can traverse the views and sum up the total height and then use that as the layout height.

Comment: I know I can set it manually, the question is how to get it to actually wrap.

Comment: @hotboysam i answered your question in the second part. You need to find the heights and sum them up. the dialog's height is determined before the layouts and that's why you can't wrap it by just using an xml tag.